# Postgresql archive_command on a cascading standby server

Tags: postgresql

I've found out that archive_command is only run by postgresql on a master.

If I'm running a cascading replication like:

Master -> Slave1 -> Slave2 and want to archive WAL segments on Slave1, the command is never run.

Is this correct?

If so, what if I just copy (rsync or similar) myself the WAL segments from pg_xlog directory to my archive directory? Could I then use this archive directory as the source for a restore_command in a new slave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If so, what if I just copy (rsync or similar) myself the WAL segments from pg_xlog directory to my archive directory? Could I then use this archive directory as the source for a restore_command in a new slave?

Yes, you can. You are however responsible for making sure you don't drop any log files while doing this.

For best results you probably want to do the cascading copy/rsync/whatever as part of your [`restore_command`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/archive-recovery-settings.html) on Slave1.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you are on Postgres 9.5 or 9.6, you can make this work.

On the standby, you need to set `archive_mode = always`. When Postgres sees `archive_mode = on` it will only archive WAL as the master, but `always` tells it to archive WAL even as a standby. The last section of [these docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/warm-standby.html) describes this behavior.

Of course the standby needs other suitable config to go along with that, e.g.:

```
archive_mode = always
hot_standby = on
wal_level = replica
max_wal_senders = 3
archive_command = whatever-you-like
archive_timeout = 300
```

Basically if you tell the standby to `always` archive WAL, then it will obey `archive_command` as normal, so configure things accordingly.